# Find words does not end with a letter expression using regexp

Tags: regex

I am trying to find any word which ends 'k' letter and must be come after these letters 'a,e,o'.

Regex should find this:

```
'stack'
'kick'
'kiik'
'kimk'
'gesk'
```

and should not find belows:

```
'book'
'beak'
'aiok'
```

For this gain i use this reguler expression :

> (?![aeo]+k)^.*?$

. But it does not work.

Comment: All the words end with `k` ? and you say `any word which does not ends 'k'`

Comment: Good point @vks, i edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^.*(?<![aeo])k$
```

You can use this as all your words are ending with `k`.See demo.The `lookbehind` will separate out the words having `aeo` just before the last `k`.

https://regex101.com/r/cD5jK1/3

Comment: @KennethK. after this solution it is simple to figure other simple problems out. I neded this core expression. 123ck is a word according to my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this negation based regex:

```
^.*[^aeo]k$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aN1tE6/2)

Comment: Thank @anubhava but your expression finds 'boot' too. The "boot" word ends "t" not "k".

Comment: Ah damn you edited the question after I posted my answer

Comment: That's okay but it looked like my answer was for a different question otherwise as you can see in my edited answer that solution was pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

You may not have provided enough information, but I don't see why any sort of lookaround is warranted here. You should be able to simply use:

```
\b[A-Za-z]*[aeo]k\b
```

Word boundaries ( \b ) will help you limit this pattern to only words. If you need to account for hyphens, then you could adjust the first range to include hyphen as well.